# In LTspice simulation Voltage spikes are observerd across drain and source of MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, pwm, switching

I am simulating the below circuit on LTspice.
[image: Spice Circuit]

A PWM signal is  applied to the gate of MOSFET M1.

[image: Gate to source PWM signal]

I expect to see a waveform similar to gate source waveform across the drain and souce of the MOSFET. Instead the below waveform is observed.

[image: Drain to source voltage]

I think this is due to parasitics capacitances of the FET but don't know the exact reason. Can someone please help me understand the same?

PWM signal specifications -
[image: PWM signal]

Comment: Please use the identical time scale for each waveform. Don't use unfathomable net names; name the nodes you wish to measure so they can be unambiguously related to the schematic.

Comment: Please also show the drain current.